# Selenium can't find element by id python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know there are alot of questions like this one, but none seems to work.

This is the code i'm using

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'captcha_input'))
    )
    print("done")
except:
    print("error")
```

There is an iframe in the page but the element im looking for isn't inside it, but I tried it anyways:

```
try:
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'captcha_input'))
    )
    print("done")
except:
    print("error")
```

The output of both is "error".
Any ideas?

Comment: The output of both is "error". Any ideas? - what is the error ? also is it a captcha ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay you are using ID, but it's Name, so try changing that and see if that works :

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'captcha_input'))
    )
    print("done")
except:
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `id` property in the HTML if you want to get it by ID:

```
<input id="captcha_input" name="captcha_input" value="" placeholder="Please input the chars in left captcha" size="30" style="height:34px; padding:6px 12px; font-size:14px; line-height:1.428; color:#666; border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:4px; box-shadow:inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);">
```

The `name` property and the `id` property are not interchangeable.